# Laravel count() вернуть нулевые значение сгруппированные по дате

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Добрый день. 
Есть таблица в БД со статистикой следующей структуры:

```
order_id int(11) 
server_id int(11) 
name varchar(255) 
phone varchar(255) 
email varchar(255) 
offer_id varchar(255) 
ip varchar(255) 
ac_status varchar(255) 
created_at timestamp NULL
```

Есть запрос в Laravel который возвращает сумму записей за промежуток, в моем случае за неделю сгруппированную по дням. Запрос :

```
Stats::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(),])
        ->where('ac_status', $status)
        ->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as date')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(order_id) as '. $status)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get();
```

Сам SQL запрос выглядит вот так, пример:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as date, 
       COUNT(order_id) as holds 
FROM stats 
WHERE ac_status = 'hold' 
  AND created_at BETWEEN '2017-06-28' AND '2017-07-02' 
GROUP BY date;
```

Данный запрос возвращает мне результат вида:

- 2017-06-29 - 4
- 2017-06-30 - 2

а необходимо что бы возвращал полную разбивку вместе с нулевыми значениями:

- 2017-06-28 - 0
- 2017-06-29 - 4
- 2017-06-30 - 2
- 2017-06-31 - 0
- 2017-07-01 - 0

Пробовал добавлять условие

```
->havingRaw("COUNT(order_id) >= 0")
```

Но ничего не получается. Можно ли вернуть такой результат запросом Query Builder?

Comment: Сервер не умеет возвращать данные, которых у него нет. Это я про даты, отсутствующие в таблице. Вам нужна дополнительно опорная таблица дат в заданном промежутке (возможно, динамически создаваемая в запросе).

Comment: А как в моем случае граммотно было бы сделать динамически создаваему таблицу в самом запросе?

Answer (score 0):

В условиях чистого MySQL запрос мог бы выглядеть так (это только схема, идея, а не реализация и даже не шаблон):

```
SELECT @startdate + INTERVAL dummy.delta DAY AS date
     , COALESCE(subquery.count, 0) AS count
FROM (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... UNION SELECT 6) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN (запрос расчёта статистики по дням) AS subquery 
       ON (@startdate + INTERVAL dummy.delta) = subquery.date
```

Как что-то подобное реализовывать в Laravel - понятия не имею.

PS. Оформил ответом, потому что в формате комментария оно никак не поместится.